# Is Ruby 2.1.5p273 compatible with Rails 4.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compatibility

I tried to run a local website using a tutorial, but it didn't work for some reason. When I looked in the RailsInstaller directory, there was a folder that says "Ruby2.1.0". Does this mean that it's only compatible with Ruby 2.1.0? How can I install a Ruby version compatible with a particular Rails version?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1. I'm not sure if that's the OS or not though. I barely know anything about computers -_-.

Comment: The ABI version of 2.1.5 is 2.1.0. Use `ruby -v` (shell) or `p RUBY_VERSION` (ruby) to get the actual version.

Comment: I used `ruby -v` and it says the version is 2.1.5p273.

Comment: Yes, Ruby 4.2.1 is compatible with Rails 4.2.1. Do you have any errors or a stack trace that could help us figure out why it's not running?

Comment: @looby I'm really convinced that Ruby 4.2.1 will not be compatible with Rails 4.2.1, however, no one knows what the future has for us. :)

Comment: Haha you got me there. Ruby 2.1.5*